# $scope getting updated whereas a new entry should be created

Tags: angularjs

I want new entries to be added when I enter something in textbox and press a button, but instead the same entry I created the first time is getting updated. The code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.ss = [];
  $scope.getPlate = function() {
    //$scope.plate1= abc;
    $scope.ss = [
      {plate1: 'some plate 1'},
      {plate1: 'some plate 2'},
      {plate1: 'some plate 3'},
      {plate1: $scope.newplate}
    ]
    var i = 0;    
    for (i=0; i<$scope.ss.plate1.length; i++) {
      alert(i);
    }
  }
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="xx in ss">
            <td>
                {{xx.plate1}}
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newplate"/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="getPlate()"/>
</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: If my answer solved your question you can always mark it as accepted by checking the tick mark next to it

Answer (score 1):

You're just overwriting the fourth object in your `$scope.ss` array. You should push new objects into the array on clicking the button:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){

   $scope.ss = [
      {plate1: 'some plate 1'},
      {plate1: 'some plate 2'},
      {plate1: 'some plate 3'},
      {plate1: $scope.newplate}
   ];
    $scope.addPlate = function(){
      $scope.ss.push({plate1: $scope.newplate});
      $scope.newplate = ''; //To clear the input box after adding a new item
    };

});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="xx in ss">
      <td>{{xx.plate1}}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="text" ng-model="newplate"/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="addPlate()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"